# Are conditional group substitutions possible in `jq` ? if so how?

Tags: shell, jq, gsub, substitution

Consider the situation:

```
echo '"field:bla"\n"field:"' \
| jq ' . | gsub( "^field:(?<val>.+?)?$" ; "(?(val)value=\(.val)|NULL)" )'
```

We're taking in a list of strings of the form: `field:<VALUE>`, where `<VALUE>` can be either `''` (empty), or one or more characters.
The objective is to return: `NULL` if `<VALUE>` is `''` (empty), or `value=<VALUE>` if non-empty.

the question is, can `jq` do this using conditional substitution ? based on whether or not the group `<val>` is set ? if so what is the syntax ? or is this not supported ?

---

> PS: it's not a problem of whether this can be done, or how to do it, i'm just wondering if jq's gsub supports conditional group substitution, and if so what's the right syntax for it.

Comment: Remember, you can do a regex match and decide _after it's done_ if you want to call `gsub`. Though if you do a capture you don't necessarily need gsub at all; you can construct a new string from the capture results without using it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you mean like use `capture` and then some conditional `if ..`?

Comment: Yup. Or `test`, or... well, there's no shortage of ways that could be done, really. `jq` is a powerful enough language that "not supported" isn't really a thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, honestly, it's not a problem of whether this can be done, or how to do it, i'm just wondering if jq's `gsub` supports conditional group substitution

Comment: Gotcha. I'd guess that it doesn't and that you want a separate `if`. Whether that `if` operates on `test` vs `capture` depends on how you want to structure things; if you're attached to gsub I'd stick to `test`.

Comment: Not `gsub`, but how about `jq 'select(index(":") != length - 1) // null'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to a "conditional substitution" within `sub` would be along these lines:

```
(echo "field:bla"; echo "field:") |
  jq -rR 'sub( "^field:(?<val>.*)$" ; "value=\(.val | if length==0 then "NULL" else . end )" ) '
```

This produces:

```
value=bla
value=NULL
```

You might also like to consider this alternative, which produces the same result:

```
(echo "field:bla"; echo "field:") |
  jq -rR 'sub( "^(field:(?<val>.+)|field:)$" ; "value=\(.val // "NULL")" )'
```

In both these cases, replacing `sub` by `gsub` has no effect on the results.